# websocket scalability

Tags: performance, websocket, cluster-computing

I have looked around a bit on websockets, and I have a pretty concrete question:
Can websockets actually be scaled over different servers, or are they always limited to one single server?

It seems that this is an issue I've repeatedly bumped into in the docs I have found, but maybe they were incomplete or things evolved. It seems for example as heroku even doesn't support websockets at all(?)

Comment: Note Heroku now supports websockets, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websockets

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your application, but in general, there is no reason you can't load balance websocket connections to multiple machines in the same way as any other TCP connection.

Comment: WebSockets are simply a persistent connection rather than requests and responses. Holding connections open is generally more resource intensive but, as @zaphoyd says, ultimately they are just TCP connections. The OpenShift platform wrote a [good post](https://openshift.redhat.com/community/blogs/paas-websockets) which includes the challenges that they are facing by offering WebSockets. Heroku will have to overcome similar challenges. These are the problems we have overcome with [Pusher](http://pusher.com).